# Temporarily disable all events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this part of javascript code :

```
$('a').on('mouseenter', function() {console.log('you just hovered a link')});
```

And that sometimes, I want to disable all events because the page is for example, loading. I can achieve this via :

```
$(*).off();
```

However, how can i re-enable all events when page finished loading ?

Comment: You could block UI, using for example http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: @A.Wolff BlockUI could have been great but when you unblockUI, the mouseenter event will be triggered if you are on the link.

Comment: Ya, that's the expected behaviour so explain instead what you are expecting?

Comment: Actually my case is the following : the user hovers a link (mouseenter), and that will show a tooltip. When he click on it, I want to disable all events (hovering, click on other parts of page, etc...) and load via ajax some content. When loading is finished, I want to re-enable all the events, but NOT show the tooltip (mouseenter).

Comment: I wrote this plugin long time ago, maybe it could fit your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/LLkj8eyn/  `$("a").freezeEvents(); $("a").unFreezeEvents();`  This handles delegated events too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can rather bind the event when document is ready:

```
 $(function(){
   $('a').on('mouseenter', function() {console.log('you just hovered a link')});
 });
```

and when it comes to other conditions, for example when animation is running. you can set some variable(say isanimationruning) to true and check the variable state to determine whether hover needs to be used or not:

```
$('a').on('mouseenter', function() {
 if(!isanimationruning)
   console.log('you just hovered a link')
});
```

Comment: Page loading was an example. I can imagine you also want to disable events while an animation is going on, or an AJAX request is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using detach function if you can.
Check out the example for function [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/washington_guedes/rtonjcym/14/

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    if( $(this).val() === "0")
        $(this).html("Click here to disable").val("1");
    else
        $(this).html("Click here to enable").val("0");
});

$("#action").on("click", function(){
    if( $("button").val() === "0") return;

    // function implementation
    $(this).css({"background-color": "#" 
        + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
        + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
        + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)});

});
```

I stored in button's value: zero or one... and used this code in the functions:

```
.. function .. (){
  if( $("button").val() === "0") return;
  ...
} ..
```

Comment: toggle(fn,fn) has been removed from jQuery 1.9+ and anyway doesn't answer question at all